# Call buisness layer methods from controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, controller

---

I would like to use buisness layer methods in the controller and i keep getting nullPointerException. Well i know it's because i can't instanciate a buisness object suince i'm dealing with the interface. So how can i call buisness methods from controller through the buisness interface? here is a sample buisness interface:

```
public interface ICompagnieBuisness {
public String depa="";
String depString(String dep);   }
```

here is the conroller where i would like to call the depString(String dep) method to return a String that i'll put in the message used in the view:

```
`package com.crun.controller;
@Controller
public class HelloWorld {
@Autowired
private static ICompagnieBuisness icb;
public void setIcb() {
    this.icb = icb;
    }
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    String dep=icb.depString(a);
    String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
            + "<h3>***Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>      </div><br><br>";
    return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
}
}`
```

here is the business class:
    package com.crun.buisness;

```
import java.util.List;

import com.crunc.dao.ICompagnieDAO;

public class ICompagnieBuisnessImpl implements ICompagnieBuisness{
private static ICompagnieDAO dao;
public String depa;
public String depString(String dep) {
    dep="Message sent from buisness layer";
    return dep;
}
}
```

And here is the error

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [crun] in context with path     [/CrunSpringMVCTutorial] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested     exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.crun.controller.CrunHelloWorld.helloWorld(CrunHelloWorld.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandl    erMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
at     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.in    vokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.ha ndle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why did you initiate your ICompagnieBuisness as static?

Comment: I used it differently earlier, it doesn't  have to be static, but i don't know how to use the business methods in the controller through the business interface.

Comment: If you want to @Autowired your ICompagnieBuisness, then your annotation must be over the icb property not below.

Comment: I just updated the code like u said, and tried still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please post your all exceptions, CompagnieBuisness class so that we can track the problem clearly. Did you use @Service annotation in your CompagnieBuisness class?

Comment: Yes please, i just did. And no i did not use the @Service annotation. The exception i'm having is because i do not know how to use methods through an interface properly.

Comment: In the line `String dep=icb.depString(a);`, where did `a` come from?

Answer (score 0):

For you to inject the instance of the `ICompagnieBuisness` to your controller, make sure that an implementation of the interface is known by Spring (it should be a Spring bean). You can make it a Spring bean by annotating it with either `@Component`, `@Repository` or `@Service`. In your case, it is more contextually right to use `@Service` because it is the business layer. Also, you cannot autowire a spring bean to a static field, so remove the static keyword in the field declaration.